# Interactive forms with PHP and Ajax via JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom

I can't make the html loaded via ajax update the DOM. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//atpc.info/f/styles.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//atpc.info/f/form.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//atpc.info/f/pesquisa.css" media="all">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//atpc.info/f/t/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form_p" action="">

    <fieldset class="p_test">
        <legend>Test question text?</legend>
        <label for="p_test_y"><input type="radio" id="p_test_y" name="p_test" value="y">Yes!</label>
        <label for="p_test_n"><input type="radio" id="p_test_n" name="p_test" value="n">No!</label>
        <a class="continue_r">Continue &rarr;</a>
    </fieldset>

    <small id="update_p"></small> <span id="status_p"></span>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('label').css('display','block');

    $('a.continue_r').live('click',function(event) {
        var id_p=$('input:radio:first').attr('name');
        var v_r=$('input:radio:checked').val();
        alert(v_r);

        $.post(
            'test.php',
            { id_p:id_p, v_r:v_r },
            function(data){
                alert('Retorno:\n' + data);
                //$('form').append($(data).hide().fadeIn('slow'));
                $('body').append(data);
                $('label').css('display','block');
            }
        );
    });

});
```

PHP:

```
<?
if(!empty($_REQUEST['id_p'])) $id_p=$_REQUEST['id_p'];
else die('Ops! no id_p');

if(!empty($_REQUEST['v_r'])) $v_r=$_REQUEST['v_r'];
else die('Ops! no v_r');

if($_REQUEST['id_p']=='p_test1') die('Victory!!!');

echo<<<FORM
<fieldset class="p_test1">
    <legend>Test 1 question text?</legend>
    <small>Last question was $id_p and you option was $v_r</small>
    <label for="p_test1_y"><input type="radio" id="p_test1_y" name="p_test1" value="ohy">Oh, Yes!</label>
    <label for="p_test1_n"><input type="radio" id="p_test1_n" name="p_test1" value="ohn">Oh, No!</label>
    <a class="continue_r">Continue &rarr;</a>
</fieldset>
FORM;
?>
```

For those interested, here is the final working JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('label').css('display','block');

    $('a.continue_r').live('click',function(event) {

        //var fieldset=$(this).closest('fieldset');
        var fieldset=$(this).parent('fieldset');
        //alert(fieldset.attr('class'));

        //var id_p=$('input:radio').attr('name');
        //var id_p=fieldset.attr('class');
        var id_p=$('fieldset:last').attr('class');
        var v_r=$('input:radio:checked:last').val();
        if(v_r=='') v_r=$('textarea:last').val();

        fieldset.hide();

        //alert('id_p = '+id_p+' - v_r = '+v_r);

        $.post(
            'test.php',
            { id_p:id_p, v_r:v_r },
            function(data){
                //alert('Retorn:\n' + data);
                $('body').append($(data).hide().fadeIn('slow'));
                //$('body').append($(data));
                //$('body').append($data);
                $('label').css('display','block');
                //console.log(data);
            }
        );
    });

});
```

Comment: http://atpc.info/f/t/test.htm seems to work correctly for me.

Comment: Did you try to set the fourth argument to 'html'; i.e. expect HTML return?

Comment: @Grim, choose Yes in the first question than choose No in the second. You will see that the alert continues to show Yes... The DOM was not updated...

Comment: I changed `$('form').append($(data).hide().fadeIn('slow'));` to `$('body').append(data);` to make things simpler and to be more close to the example here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Wayne Khan, I did not get what you mean... are reffering to the ajax call?

Comment: did you try `$('body).append($(data));`?  (on a side note, it should be `var v_r=$('input:radio:first:checked').val();` in case you uncheck first radio button )

Comment: I guess `.live()` is doing his job just fine. The real problem is the way I am getting the variables `id_p` and `v_r`. According to the JQuery documentation at http://api.jquery.com/live/ under the paragraph "Event Delegation": "This test is performed by checking if $(event.target).closest(".clickme") is able to locate a matching element." So, I am getting the data from the first fieldset not the newest loaded via ajax...

Comment: @Roger, sorry no that wasn't the problem. I'll post a full answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the DOM is updated. But I think the selector is wrong.

Try this?

```
$(':radio:checked:last')
```

This will get the last checked radio input, which is probably what you want instead. Based on the markup:

```
<fieldset class="p_test">
    <legend>Test question text?</legend>
    <label for="p_test_y"><input type="radio" id="p_test_y" name="p_test" value="y">Yes!</label>
    <label for="p_test_n"><input type="radio" id="p_test_n" name="p_test" value="n">No!</label>
    <a class="continue_r">Continue &rarr;</a>
</fieldset>
```

The fieldset tag wraps everything up, so your handler can be defined like:

```
$('a.continue_r').live('click', function() {
    var $fieldset = $(this).parent('fieldset');

    // Do stuff like $fieldset.find(), which ensures that your matches are contained therein.
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am making some tests with `var fieldset=$(this).closest('fieldset'); alert(fieldset.attr('class'));`. You can see the updated js here: http://atpc.info/f/t/test.js

Comment: I think I got it: to get the latest fieldset class and radion value: `var id_p=$('fieldset:last').attr('class'); var v_r=$('input:radio:checked:last').val();` -  http://atpc.info/f/t/test.htm

Comment: Yes, it worked! :) FYI, the fieldset tag wraps the entire markup, you could've also used something like $(this).parent('fieldset').

Comment: By the way, @Wayne Khan, what are you using to conclude that "the fieldset tag wraps the entire markup"?